# Format CDATA Type from RSS with C# XDocument or XPath in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, rss, cdata

I'm trying to format and get the image, text etc.. to give a good look and feel.

The XML is something like this:

```
xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
```

And the content is:

```
<content:encoded>
<![CDATA[
<p><a href="http://i2.wp.com/geekytheory.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Screen-Shot-     2013-11-11-at-11.38.50.png"><img class="size-full wp-image-7447 aligncenter" alt="Screen    Shot 2013-11-11 at 11.38.50" src="http://i2.wp.com/geekytheory.com/wp-  content/uploads/2014/03/Screen-Shot-2013-11-11-at-11.38.5
]]>
<![CDATA[
0.png?resize=788%2C644" data-recalc-dims="1" /></a></p> <p style="text-align:   justify">
</p>]]>
< /content:encoded>
```

At first what I will get is the image or example: he is in **content:encoded/p/a/img/src**

the code that I try is:

```
private ObservableCollection<RssItem> ParseXmlString(string xmlString)
    {
        XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
        XNamespace xmns = @"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/";
        XNamespace xmnsContent = @"http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/";
        var itemsList = xmlDoc.Descendants("item").Select(i => new RssItem()
        {
            Author = i.Element(xmns + "creator").Value,
            Title = i.Element("title").Value,
            Description = i.Element("description").Value,
            Content = i.Element(xmnsContent + "encoded").Value,
            Image = i.Element(xmnsContent + "encoded").XPathSelectElement("//p//a//img[@src]").Value,
            Date = DateTime.Parse(i.Element("pubDate").Value)
        }).ToList();

        return new ObservableCollection<RssItem>(itemsList);
    }
```

The ***Content = i.Element(xmnsContent + "encoded").Value*** give me all the content without formatting something like this:
[image]

And for exctract the image or some other element from the CData I get a error.
***Image = i.Element(xmnsContent + "encoded").XPathSelectElement("//p//a//img[@src]").Value*** is giving error.

I tried this way too, but giving the same error.

```
Image = i.Element(xmnsContent+"encoded").Element("p").Element("a").Element("img").Attribute("src").Value
```

Thanks for all and greetings!!

Comment: Nobody can help me? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally with a FlowDocumentScrollViewer an the XmlToXamlConverter I get the solution:

```
<FlowDocumentScrollViewer
   Document="{Binding Content, Converter={StaticResource HtmlToFlowDocConverter}}"/>
```

After we need to add a Converter like:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
  CultureInfo culture)
    {

        var xaml = HtmlToXamlConverter.ConvertHtmlToXaml((string)value, true);
        var flowDocument = XamlReader.Parse(xaml);
        if (flowDocument is FlowDocument)
            SubscribeToAllHyperlinks((FlowDocument)flowDocument);
        return flowDocument;
    }

    private void SubscribeToAllHyperlinks(FlowDocument flowDocument)
    {
        var hyperlinks = GetVisuals(flowDocument).OfType<Hyperlink>();
        foreach (var link in hyperlinks)
            link.RequestNavigate += LinkRequestNavigate;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> GetVisuals(DependencyObject root)
    {
        foreach (var child in
           LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(root).OfType<DependencyObject>())
        {
            yield return child;
            foreach (var descendants in GetVisuals(child))
                yield return descendants;
        }
    }

    private void LinkRequestNavigate(object sender,
      System.Windows.Navigation.RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri));
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
      CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Finally we will add the XmlToXamlConverter from [here](http://jacob4u2.blogspot.de/2009/09/bind-html-to-textblock-with-html-to.html) and another from [here](https://github.com/AfterbuyAxel/WPF-RichText-Editor/blob/master/src/WpfRichText/XamlToHtmlParser/HtmlToXamlConverter.cs).

Another helpfull article for me was [this](http://www.elegant-software.net/2013/07/rendering-html-in-wpf.html).

Greetings!